# SSIS package working in SSDT and not working in SQL server after I deploy it

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssdt-bi

I have an SSIS package that creates a next day folder based on the previous day folder in a directory, when i run the package directly from SSDT it generates the folder,however when i deploy the package to Sql server intergration catalogue and excute,i get a success message but the folder is not created.

variables on the script task
[image]

variable declaration
[image]
[image]

Please see the script task code below:

```
   public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        string DataLocation = Dts.Variables["User::FolderLocation"].Value.ToString();

        string[] Folders = Directory.GetDirectories(DataLocation);


        List<String> listFolders = new List<String>();
        List<String> listFoldersonly = new List<String>();
        List<int> lens = new List<int>();
        List<String> dates = new List<String>();
        List<DateTime> dd = new List<DateTime>();

        //get list of folders in the Directory
        if (Folders.Length > 0)
        {

            for (int x = 0; x < Folders.Length; x++)
            {

                listFolders.Add(Folders[x].ToString());
                lens.Add(Folders[x].Length);


            }
        }
        //store list of folders in an array
        string[] arrayFolders = listFolders.ToArray();
        int[] arrayLens = lens.ToArray();


        DateTime minDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
        DateTime maxDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime nextdate;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayFolders.Length; i++)
        {
            //subtring the date from the folderlocation string
            dates.Add(arrayFolders[i].ToString().Substring(arrayLens[i] - 10));

            dd.Add(DateTime.Parse(arrayFolders[i].ToString().Substring(arrayLens[i] - 10)));

            //get the max and min date
            if (dd[i].Date < minDate)
                minDate = dd[i];
            if (dd[i] > maxDate)
                maxDate = dd[i];

        }

        nextdate = maxDate.AddDays(1);
        string nxtdate = nextdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        String newpath = DataLocation + "\\" + nxtdate;


        Dts.Variables["User::CopyFolder"].Value = newpath.ToString();
        Dts.Variables["User::ReturnDate"].Value = nextdate.ToString();


        Directory.CreateDirectory(newpath);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Comment: You probably have more than one database due to connection string connecting to a different server or mdf file.

Comment: The default value for `Dts.TaskResult` is 0, which is success so if `Directory.CreateDirectory(newpath);` raises an exception `Dts.TaskResult` will not be set. Put a `try...catch` block round `Directory.CreateDirectory(newpath);` and see what happens. `Directory.CreateDirectory()` returns a `DirectoryInfo` object which you can also inspect.

Comment: Is the catalog on a SQL Server that is the same as your workstation? It creates that folder wherever the package is running. Which may not be your workstation.

Comment: Hi, I created a different package ,just a simple one that loads a text file and it loads successfully when i deploy it.on the same environment

Comment: and is that text file in Users\Documents? it's a bad idea to use User folders for server type operations